# Trying to create a sftp server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, sftp

I'm trying to create a SFTP server with nodejs with https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sftp-server

But im getting this error: **Error: No supported authentication methods available**

I'm using this code:

```
var SFTPServer = require("node-sftp-server");

var srv = new SFTPServer("private.ppk");
srv.listen(45);
console.warn("server listening on port 45");

srv.on("connect", function (auth)
{
    console.warn("authentication attempted");
    if (auth.method !== 'password' || auth.username !== "brady" || auth.password !== "test")
    {
        return auth.reject();
    }
    console.warn("We haven't *outhright* accepted yet...");
    var username = auth.username;
    var password = auth.password;

    return auth.accept(function (session)
    {
        console.warn("Okay, we've accepted, allegedly?");
    });
});

srv.on("end", function ()
{
    return console.warn("Example says user disconnected");
});
```

What can cause this error?

Comment: At which point do you get this error?

Comment: When I try to autenticate on a sftp program

Comment: So you don't get the `connect` event, but since you don't handle `on.('error')`, the exception is making your program close?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that this is an old post, but in case this helps: your sFTP client is likely to try authentication method 'none' first before others. However, because you're rejecting and not offering the list of authentication methods that your server *will* accept and therefore the sFTP client should next try, the connection ends there. To do this, replace `return auth.reject();` with `return auth.reject(['password', 'publickey'], false);`. Your array can be whatever you like of accepted methods, so you may only wish to use `['password']`. The second argument is if the authentication is partially accepted by your server. I do not yet appreciate the full nuance of this so far but will update this answer if I do.